# ¿Cómo destructurar un Array dentro de un if en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, programación-funcional, lógica

Basicamente tengo este codigo:

```js
if(paintedValues.length > 0) {
                    let paintDistance;
                    paintedValues.forEach(element => {
                        const dx = Math.abs( x - element[0])
                        const dy = Math.abs(y - element[1])
                        paintDistance = Math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
                        spacesSkip.push(paintDistance < Mouse.radius);
                    });
                }

                if( (distance < Mouse.radius) || spacesSkip.map) {
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y)] = red
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +1] = green 
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +2] = blue 
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +3] = opacity 
                }else {
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y)] = 0
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +1] = 0
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +2] = 0
                    blankData.data[pixels(x, y) +3] = opacity
                } 
            }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que los valores dentro de mi array spacesSkip sean destructurados dentro del if para tener algo así como: valor|| valor || valor .... intente de muchas forma pero no eh encontrado solución, ya intente con un for,  .forEach, .map, etc.

Si conocen otra manera de hacerlo y llegar al mismo resultado será una respuesta perfectamente valida y se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 3):

Creo entender que el objetivo final es evaluar cada elemento del array y retornar `true` si **al menos** un elemento del array cumple la condición (en este caso ser un valor Truthy), si es así, puedes utilizar el método `some`.

```javascript
....
if( (distance < Mouse.radius) || spacesSkip.some(e => e))
....
```

**Donde**

1. spacesSkip es un arreglo
2. El argumento del método `some` es una función que realiza la condición y retorna true/false si esta se cumple o no.

Al final el método `some` retorna True si **al menos** un elemento del arreglo cumple la condición